# How to compare every objects in iterator with compareTo

Tags: java

I have a model `class Person` which implements the `Comparable` interface and a `compareTo(Personne o)` method which returns the proper int depending on the person's age.

**Usecase:** I want to check if all the persons inside the collection have the same age with an iterator

What I have so far:

```
while (collectionOfPerson.hasNext()) {
    Person pers = collectionOfPerson.next();
    if (pers.comparTo(collectionOfPerson.next()) == 0) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Java8? Maybe with a stream could be more easy

Comment: yes I'm using java 8, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enough to grab only the first person and compare this to every other person, as you are testing if all have the same age.

Also, your comparison isn't correct, you have:

```
pers.comparTo(collectionOfPerson.next()) == 0
```

So you are trying to compare the current person to the next. But you have not tested if there is another person yet. So if you reached the end you will try to access a non existing person, yielding an error. You could easily fix that by comparing to the person of the last iteration. But, as said, you don't need that and could just compare to the first person every time.

Also, you should test for mismatch, not for matching ages.

```
Person first = collectionOfPerson.next();
while (collectionOfPerson.hasNext()) {
    Person other = collectionOfPerson.next();
    if (first.comparTo(other) != 0) {
        // Found mismatch, abort
        return false;
    }
}
// Didn't found mismatch
return true;
```

Or a `Stream` example that does not use `Iterator`:

```
Person first = persons.iterator().next();

boolean allSameAge = persons.stream()
    .allMatch(p -> p.compareTo(first) == 0);
```

An alternative using the enhanced for loop (for-each):

```
Person first = persons.iterator().next();
for (Person other : persons) {
    if (other.compareTo(first) != 0) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

The following example filters all persons with the same age, only different ages remain. By that you can also easily collect the persons with other ages:

```
Person first = persons.iterator().next();
List<Person> otherAgePersons = persons.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.compareTo(first) != 0)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Please tell me the reason for the down-vote, I'd like to improve my answer.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Down vote (not me) was probably because originally this was comparing `Person` objects for equality, not the age.

Comment: From another perspective could you not just put all ages into a `Set` (normal loop) and see if the set size is greater than 1 at the end, would interesting to see the most efficient?

Comment: Will work. But it will be faster to not setup another data-structure. The problem is decidable by just iterating every person once and checking each person one time.

Answer (score 3):

> Usecase: I want to check if all the persons inside the collection have the same age with an iterator

You can take advantage of streams along with an `Iterator` if you'd like, assuming you a `getAge` method within `Person` and `collectionOfPerson` is **not** empty:

```
if (!collectionOfPerson.hasNext()) {
    return;
}

int age = collectionOfPerson.next().getAge();

collectionOfPerson.stream()
                  .mapToInt(Person::getAge)
                  .allMatch(i -> i == age);
```

If you're dead-set on solely using an `Iterator<Person>`, then you were close!  You can keep track of a `boolean` and break out of the loop if any of the elements in the collection do not match the age of the first element:

```
if (!collectionOfPerson.hasNext()) {
    return;
}

int age = collectionOfPerson.next().getAge();

boolean allMatch = true;

while (collectionOfPerson.hasNext()) {
    if (collectionOfPerson.next().getAge() != age) {
        allMatch = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (allMatch) {
    // All of the ages are the same!
}
```

Comment: OP wants to use `Iterator` *(you even quoted OP saying so)*, and very likely hasn't learned about streaming yet.

Comment: Then it's a great time to learn!  I'll update my answer with an `Iterator` solution then.

Comment: And OP probably will in another few months when they get that far in class, but they are not there yet.

Comment: Still not a reason to downvote. You people are far to quick pulling that button..

Comment: A stream-based solution could also be `if (persons.stream().map(Person::getAge).collect(Collectors.toSet()).size()==1) ...`. But it's not clear whether a `getAge` method actually exists. The asker only mentioned the `compareTo` method....

Answer (score 2):

I advocate for one solution using only streams.

```
Optional<Person> anyPerson = persons.stream().findAny();

boolean allSameAge = persons.stream()
    .allMatch(p -> p.compareTo(anyPerson.get()) == 0);
```

I have to say that's not a semantic solution but it doesn't requires more work implementing new functions.

Following [DDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) to get a more semantic code you can change *compareTo* function for another which could be placed in Person class and have this contract:

```
public boolean hasSameAge(Person p);
```